# How to get Google OAuth ID access token in angular where i used Firebase AUTH Rest API for authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

In my Angular Project, I want to use Firebase Auth REST API for authentication. This is firebase documentation for that [Firebase Documentation for Auth Rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential). For Sign in with OAuth credential to use sign-in with google, I need Google OAuth ID token and provider ID corresponding to the OAuth credential. How can I get this or generate this? I have generated CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET from the Google developer console but don't know how to proceed with this. I am using firebase for authentication